# Copy file to Rules.d directory

Tags: linux, permissions, udev, file-copy

I'm using Raspbian on a Pi 3+. Please tell me how I can get the permission to copy a new file to the `/etc/udev/rules.d` directory. 
The file contains

```
KERNEL==“ttyUSB*”, MODE=“0666” 
KERNEL==“ttyACM*”, MODE=“0666” 
KERNEL==“ttyS*”, MODE=“0666”
```

Comment: What have you tried and what errors are you getting? What user are you when trying to copy the file?

Answer (score 0):

1. `sudo cp rulefile /etc/udev/rules.d/`
2. `su -`
   `cp rulefile /etc/udev/rules.d/`